# 3D Engine stretches objects out while rotating

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d-engine

I made a little 3d engine.

But I have some problems with the rotating functions.
They make the object stretch out from time to time.
Here's the math:

```
this.rotateX = function(angle) {
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        this.points[i].y = sin * this.points[i].z + cos * this.points[i].y;
        this.points[i].z = -sin * this.points[i].y + cos * this.points[i].z;
    }
}

this.rotateY = function(angle) {
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        this.points[i].x = cos * this.points[i].x - sin * this.points[i].z;
        this.points[i].z = sin * this.points[i].x + cos * this.points[i].z;
    }
}

this.rotateZ = function(angle) {
    var cos = Math.cos(angle);
    var sin = Math.sin(angle);

    for(var i = 0; i < this.points.length; i++) {
        this.points[i].x = cos * this.points[i].x + sin * this.points[i].y;
        this.points[i].y = -sin * this.points[i].x + cos * this.points[i].y;
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, but are you sure you're rotating around the centre of the object...

Comment: By some more testing with only using one of the functions I see the functions stretch out the object in some way... Edited.

Comment: Maybe it's by a int-rounding problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.points[i].y = sin * this.points[i].z + cos * this.points[i].y;
this.points[i].z = -sin * this.points[i].y + cos * this.points[i].z;
```

You are calculating `y` and using this new `y` to calculate `z`. You should probably use old  `y` (before rotation):

```
var y = sin * this.points[i].z + cos * this.points[i].y;
var z = -sin * this.points[i].y + cos * this.points[i].z;
this.points[i].y = y;
this.points[i].z = z;
```

Comment: Thanx, the solution is a small thing sometimes :P